# Finding an angle in a triangle, when the length of one side is unknown and the distances from each vertex to an arbitrary point is known

Tags: geometry

Given the triangle $\triangle ABN$ I would like to find the angle $\angle ANB$. The lengths of $AN$ and $BN$ are known, but the length $AB$ is unknown.

There exists another point $S$ that forms two more triangles $\triangle ANS$ and $\triangle BNS$. The lengths of $NS, AS$ and $BS$ are known. The location of $S$ is arbitrary, it may be inside or outside $\triangle ABN$.

Using these triangles $\angle ANS$ and $\angle BNS$ can be calculated. These can then be used to find $\angle ANB$. However, There are multiple ways to calculate ANB depending on the position of $S$, as shown by these two figures:

[image]

[image]

I've also come up with other equations that are required when $S$ is in different positions.

Is there a better way to find $\angle ANB$?

If there is not, is there a way to determine which of the equations to use to calculate $\angle ANB$ from $\angle ANS$ and $\angle BNS$?

The coordinates of the four points $A$, $B$, $N$ and $S$ are all unknown.

Comment: If you know the coordinates of $A,B,N$ how can $AB$ be unknown?

Comment: @MatthewBradbury You can use cosine rule to find the angle $\beta$. and then $\alpha$ and subtract them from 180 and you get $\gamma$. Again use cosine rule to find AB and the again to find the required angle.

Comment: The coordinates of all points are unknown, so unfortunately I can't just find the distance AB. $\gamma$ is also unknown.

Comment: I can find $\gamma$ individually for each position of S, the problem is I need a way to detect which technique to use to get $\gamma$ from $\alpha$ and $\beta$. As well as the two situations above ($\gamma = \alpha + \beta$ and $\gamma = 2\pi - \alpha - \beta$) S can also be in a position where I would need to do $\gamma = \beta - \alpha$ or $\gamma = \alpha - \beta$. I need a way to select one of these equations as the software I'm writing is not aware of the relative position of S, so it cannot choose one of the equations beforehand.

Comment: So you're looking for a single solution that works regardless of whether S is in the triangle, outside the triangle, or on one edge of the triangle?

Comment: Either a single solution or a way to choose between the individual solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cayley–Menger determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry_problem#Cayley.E2.80.93Menger_determinants). Writing $ab$ for the distance between $a$ and $b$, you get

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & SA^2 & SB^2 & SN^2 & 1 \\
SA^2 & 0 & AB^2 & AN^2 & 1 \\
SB^2 & AB^2 & 0 & BN^2 & 1 \\
SN^2 & AN^2 & BN^2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

This will lead to a quadratic equation in $AB^2$, which will give you two possible solutions. For each possible value of $AB^2$ you of course take the positive square root as $AB$. But that still leaves you with two solutions, and unless you have additional information, both of them are valid.

Here is one way to think about the two solutions. Since you know $AN, SA, SN$ you can construct $\triangle ANS$ uniquely up to a congruence transformation. The same holds for $\triangle BNS$ taken by itself. But if you combine them along the edge $NS$, you have to make a choice: are $A$ and $B$ on the same side of $NS$, or on different sides? Or in other words, do the triangles have the same or opposite orientation. Either solution would be valid, either would satisfy all your length requirements, but they would lead to different distances $AB$ and different angles $\gamma$. The following picture illustrates this:

[image: Illustration of ambiguity]

Once you have $AB$, you can compute $\gamma$ from that using the [cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

$$\gamma=\arccos\frac{AN^2+BN^2-AB^2}{2\cdot AN\cdot BN}$$

The result will be in the range $[0°,180°]$, i.e. unsigned and no reflex angles. Which is what's to be expected if all you have are lengths.

Comment: The wikipedia article provided a different format for the matrix so which solution should I use [yours](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve[+0+%3D+det+%28+{{0,+a^2,+b^2,+c^2},+{a^2,+0,+d^2,+e^2},+{b^2,+d^2,+0,+f^2},+{c^2,+e^2,+f^2,+0}}+%29,+d]) or [wikipedia's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve[+0+%3D+det+%28+[0,+a^2,+b^2,+c^2,+1],+[a^2,+0,+d^2,+e^2,+1],+[b^2,+d^2,+0,+f^2,+1],+[c^2,+e^2,+f^2,+0,+1],+[1,+1,+1,+1,+0]+%29,+d])

Comment: @MatthewBradbury: I made a mistake copying that, the one from Wikipedia should be correct. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: This does work, however it hasn't managed to improve on my initial technique of working out $\gamma$ using each individual equation, filtering the invalid results and then taking the minimum or maximum angle.
I suppose this is to be expected due to the lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As stated, the problem does not necessarily have a single solution. Example:

`AN = 1.0, BN = 0.65, NS = 0.92, AS = 0.81, BS = 0.35`

B's coordinates can be either {0.45509,0.354363} or 
{0.733145,0.592696}, and the values of angle ANB is different for 
these two sets of coordinates.

Note that I am using approximate numbers here, but the roundoff errors 
are small enough to be ignored.

I hope to expand on my answer by providing a closed formula for the 
two possible values of ANB (when they exist).

EDIT: General answer:

Create a Cartesian grid such that $N$ is at the origin, $A$ lies on 
the positive x axis and $S$ lies in the upper half plane. You can 
always do this using translation, rotation, and reflecting without 
affecting any lengths:

[image]

(note that $A$ and $N$ above are flipped from my counterexample 
earlier, as it turns out the calculations are easier with $N$ at the 
origin; I've also replaced the side lengths with lowercase letters 
since I'm using Mathematica to help solve this problem)

Although I've draw B and S in quadrant I, B can be in any quadrant, 
and S can be in quadrants I or II (since we explicitly chose our axis 
system so that sy > 0).

We can now find sx and sy by solving the simultaneous equations:

$\text{sx}^2+\text{sy}^2=d^2$

$(\text{sx}-c)^2+\text{sy}^2=e^2$

The are two solutions, but only one with sy > 0:

$  
   \left\{\text{sx}\to \frac{c^2+d^2-e^2}{2 c},\text{sy}\to 
    \sqrt{d^2-\frac{\left(c^2+d^2-e^2\right)^2}{4 c^2}}\right\} 
$

We can now solve for bx and by using:

$(\text{bx}-\text{sx})^2+(\text{by}-\text{sy})^2=f^2$

$\text{bx}^2+\text{by}^2=g^2$

and plugging in the values of sx and sy we found earlier, yielding two 
solutions, both valid:

$ 
   \left\{\text{bx}\to \frac{\left(c^2+d^2-e^2\right) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)+\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) 
    (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}}{4 c d^2},\text{by}\to -\frac{c^4 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)+c^2 \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) 
    (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}-2 \left(d^2+e^2\right) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)+(d-e) (d+e) \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) 
    (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}+(d-e) (d+e) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)}{4 c d^2 \sqrt{-(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) 
    (c+d+e)}}\right\} 
$

$ 
   \left\{\text{bx}\to \frac{\left(c^2+d^2-e^2\right) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)-\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) 
    (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}}{4 c d^2},\text{by}\to \frac{c^4 
    \left(-\left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)+c^2 \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) 
    (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}+2 \left(d^2+e^2\right) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)+(d-e) (d+e) \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) 
    (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}-(d-e) (d+e) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)}{4 c d^2 \sqrt{-(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) 
    (c+d+e)}}\right\} 
$

To find ABN, we simply take the arctangent of 
$\frac{\text{by}}{\text{bx}}$. Since the angle will always be between 
0 and 180 degrees (if it's larger than 180 degrees, we measure the 
angle clockwise), we can use the single argument form of arctangent 
(I'd stated incorrectly earlier than we needed the two argument 
form. This yields:

$ 
   -\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{c^4 \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)+c^2 \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) 
    (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}-2 
    \left(d^2+e^2\right) \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)+(d-e) (d+e) 
    \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) 
   (d+f+g)}+(d-e) (d+e) \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)}{\sqrt{-(c-d-e) (c+d-e) 
    (c-d+e) (c+d+e)} \left(\left(c^2+d^2-e^2\right) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)+\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) 
    (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}\right)}\right) 
$

$ 
   \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{c^4 \left(-\left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)+c^2 
    \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) 
    (d+f+g)}+2 \left(d^2+e^2\right) \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)+(d-e) (d+e) 
    \left(\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) (d+f-g) (d-f+g) 
   (d+f+g)}-(d-e) (d+e) \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)\right)}{\sqrt{-(c-d-e) (c+d-e) 
    (c-d+e) (c+d+e)} \left(\left(c^2+d^2-e^2\right) 
    \left(d^2-f^2+g^2\right)-\sqrt{(c-d-e) (c+d-e) (c-d+e) (c+d+e) (d-f-g) 
    (d+f-g) (d-f+g) (d+f+g)}\right)}\right) 
$

Mathematica can't find a simpler form for the answer, and I'm not sure 
how useful the above is, but there you have it.

Note that I assume the triangle inequality throughout. When the 
triangle inequality doesn't hold, some of the square roots above are 
of negative values, and thus have no real number solutions.

Comment: This requires knowledge of the length of AB (which is unknown for me). Unless you meant to put A at the origin instead of N?

Comment: Ugh, you're right! I knew that flipping A and N at the last second was a bad idea... I'll fix this shortly.

Comment: Answer corrected.